# “This API project is not authorized to use this API” using Google-Directions-Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-directions-api

I'm building an app using Google-Directions-Android (https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android). I'm using the API Key in the same App for maps without problems, but when I try to use the following

```
  Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                .travelMode(AbstractRouting.TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .key(getString(R.string.google_api_key))
                .withListener(this)
                .alternativeRoutes(false)
                .waypoints(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), pickupLatLng)
                .build();
        routing.execute();
```

I get an error “This API project is not authorized to use this API”. 
In my Google API console I have all the 16 maps API enabled and the only one being requested is the Maps SDK for Android. 
The API key is completely open and unrestricted. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use google direction library you will have to use your server key(auto generate for you bu google).
You can find the server key inside your console

Try replace this code :

```
.key(getString(R.string.google_api_key))
```

With the server key - like this :

```
.key(getString("your server key"))
```